# OpenSSL 3.0.0 include files difference official release conan vs github

Tags: c++, openssl, conan

I'm building an app for both Windows, Linux and Android in c++. As with many third party dependencies, the windows and linux binaries are to be found on conan (which I use for dep management) but Android is not. This is usually not a big issue, building one extra library from source. However for OpenSSL I have the suspicion that the 3.0.0 release on the official [conan center registry](https://conan.io/center/openssl) differs from the official 3.0.0 source released on [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/openssl-3.0.0).

A very simple diff suffices:

```
diff /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl
     /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl

Only  in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: asn1.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: asn1.h.inOnly in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: asn1t.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: asn1t.h.in
Only in path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: bio.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: bio.h.in
Only in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: cmp.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: cmp.h.in
diff /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/cmperr.h /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/ds/openssl-openssl-3.0.0-beta1/openssl-openssl-3.0.0-beta1/include/openssl/cmperr.h
64d63
< #  define CMP_R_MISSING_CERTID                             165
105d103
< #  define CMP_R_WRONG_CERTID                               189
Only in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: cms.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: cms.h.in
Only in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: conf.h
Only in /path/to/Downloads/openssl-openssl-3.0.0/include/openssl/: conf.h.inOnly in /path/to/.conan/data/openssl/3.0.0/_/_/package/<hash>/include/openssl/: configuration.h
...
```

Should be equal, right? It's not.
What version of OpenSSL is uploaded to conan? How do I get the matching Android version?
Or do I have to go through the trouble of building for Windows and Linux as well?

Comment: How are they differing? conan should just be pulling from github. The recipes to build openssl are public, you can check it out and see if they change things (maybe to fix bugs on certain platforms/compilers?)

Comment: Too much difference in the include files to include in the question. Before I continue with integrating into CMake and my own headers I want to be 100% sure I have the correct libraries.

Comment: Is the difference actual code or just line endings?

Comment: @hasdrubal You can show some of the first lines (say 20)

Comment: Hi! For the version you are downloading it looks like it is `3.0.0-beta1`, while ConanCenter packages `3.0.0`. Indeed, the beta version doesn't define `CMP_R_MISSING_CERTID` while the released one does.  Maybe it is just a version mismatch? The diff is huge https://github.com/openssl/openssl/compare/openssl-3.0.0-beta1...openssl-3.0.0 and it contains those changes your report in `cmperr.h` file

Comment: That might be it. Will try beta

Comment: @jgsogo is correct! Please, update it as Answer, not comment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the version you are downloading it looks like it is `3.0.0-beta1`, while ConanCenter packages `3.0.0`. Indeed, the beta version doesn't define `CMP_R_MISSING_CERTID` while the released one does. Maybe it is just a version mismatch? The diff is huge https://github.com/openssl/openssl/compare/openssl-3.0.0-beta1...openssl-3.0.0 and it contains those changes your report in `cmperr.h` file.